# How can i play audio on a bluetooth speaker using python on a raspberry pi 4 model B

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I have a script that is supposed to play sound when its triggered by an arduino,

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
import serial
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

Sound1 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/home/pi/Desktop/Refridgerator/Gamesound.wav")
Sound2 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/home/pi/Desktop/Refridgerator/Grenade.wav")

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
while 1:
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    if (line == "1"):
        play(Sound1)
    elif (line == "2"):
        play(Sound2)
    print(line)
```

I also have a systemd file to automatically start up that script when the raspberry pi is turned on,

```
[Unit] 
Description=The refridgerator thing 
After=multi-user.target 
[Service] 
Type=simple 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Refridgerator.py 
Restart=on-abort 
[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My problem is, the script works as expected when connected to a HDMI monitor(the monitor has built in speakers), but when i try to use a Bluetooth speaker that's paired, connected, and trusted, the audio wont play through the speaker, can i have help! its in python 3.

Comment: How are you telling `play` to use the Bluetooth speaker? Take a look at the `3.2 connect speaker with cable` section in the following answer: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/116843/121848

Comment: Thanks but im not trying to connect with a cable, im trying to connect with bluetooth @ukBaz

Comment: I know you are trying to connect with Bluetooth. Did you read the section? I think the person that wrote the information was making the analogy, that a wired speaker will not work if you don't connect it with a wire. And a Bluetooth speaker will not work if you don't connect to it with Bluetooth. They used the `pacmd` command to configure the routing of the audio to the Bluetooth speaker.